# In Nest.js,while I am using openai api for whisper getting this error. "Argument of type 'ReadStream' is not assignable to parameter of type 'File'. "

Tags: typescript, nestjs, openai-api, openai-whisper

To work on speech-to-text using openai API whisper model in nest.js,
I am getting the below error:

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'ReadStream' is not assignable to parameter of type 'File'.
> Type 'ReadStream' is missing the following properties from type 'File': lastModified, name, webkitRelativePath, size, and 6 more.23 fs.createReadStream(filePath)

What could be the issue?
Service
speech-to-text.service.ts

```
  async transcribeAudio(fileBuffer: Buffer): Promise<string> {
    const filePath = 'tmp/audio.mp3';

    try {
      fs.writeFileSync(filePath, fileBuffer);
      const resp = await this.openai.createTranscription(
        fs.createReadStream(filePath),
        'whisper-1'
      );
      return resp.data.text;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Transcription error:', error);
      throw new Error('Failed to transcribe the audio file.');
    } finally {
      fs.unlinkSync(filePath);
    }
  }
}
```

Controller

app.controller.ts

```
@Controller('transcription')
export class TranscriptionController {
  constructor(private readonly transcriptionService: TranscriptionService) {}

  @Post('upload')
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('audio'))
  async uploadFile(@UploadedFile() audio): Promise<string> {
    const transcription = await this.transcriptionService.transcribeAudio(audio.buffer);
    return transcription;
  }
}
```

Comment: What openai library are you using here?

Comment: It is OpenAI GPT-3 API.

Comment: What's the openai _npm_ library you are using?